# get_category_link() is returning nothing

Tags: links, categories

```
<?php 
$categories=get_categories('taxonomy=galeriak'); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name ?>"><?php the_term_thumbnail (  $category->term_id, $category->taxonomy, $size = 'thumbnail', $attr = '') ?><span><?php echo $category->name ?></span></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

I use this code to display the categories from the "galeriak" taxonomy. Everything is working, except the href part, its return nothing. I tried it with and without the echo, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`get_term_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) instead, also for consistencys sake and to future proof, use [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) instead of `get_categories`. Both work on categories/tags and all custom taxonomies.

Also check for the return of a WP_Error object ( returned when an invalid or nonexistent term is passed )